# Time fixed effects (error message)

Tags: panel-data

I want to run the a fixed effects regression in R for which I define the following formula:

time.aspects <- as.formula(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + t)
**time.total** <- plm(time.aspects, data=all, index=c("i","t"), model = "within")

x1, x2 and x3 are my independent variables. I also want to add a time factor t to account for time fixed effects.In this regard, t stands for the single years 1 to 10 (that are included in my data file).

However, if I want to consider robust standard errors in the following way:

coeftest(**time.total**, vcov. = vcovSCC(**time.total**, type = "HC3"))

the following error occurs: Mistake in 1 - diaghat : non-numerical argument for binary operator.

Does anyone know how to avoid this error message?

Comment: leave out `t` in your formula and use `plm(, model="within", effect="twoways") instead, then try again `coeftest`

Comment: Also that doesn't work. Same error

Comment: Ok, last idea: Check if your estimated model contains estimates for all coefficients as specified by your formula. plm silently drops non-estimatable coefficients (e.g. due to linear dependency).